# Conditional update_or_create with django

Tags: django, postgresql, sql-update

Test model

```
class Room(models.Model):
    """
    This stores details of rooms available
    """
    name = models.CharField(
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        max_length=100,
        help_text='Enter the name of the room'
    )
    capacity = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        help_text='Enter the number of person\'s the room can accommodate'
    )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

I want to update the model if it exists and its modified_at time is less than say x time otherwise just create the model.
For reference here it the raw sql I want django to execute.

```
INSERT INTO room VALUES (1,'2018-04-30 18:15:32.96468+04:30','2018-04-30 18:15:32.96468+04:30','Room-A',30) ON CONFLICT(id) DO UPDATE SET capacity=10 WHERE room.modified_at < '2017-04-30 18:15:32.96468+04:30';
```

Also I would like to know if the SQL query I'have written is atomic or not

Answer (score 1):

The following examples may work properly

**1st Option**

```
try:
    obj = Room.objects.get(
        id=id, # test with other fields if you want
    )
    if obj.modified_at < DATETIME:
        obj.capacity = 10
        obj.save()
    else:
        obj = Room.objects.create(
            # fields attributes
        )
except Room.DoesNotExist:
    obj = Room.objects.create(
        # fields attributes
    )
```

**2nd Option**

or you can do so with [Conditional Expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case) of django

```
from django.db.models import F, Case, When
import datetime

your_date = datetime.datetime.now()
condition = Case(When(modified_at__lt=your_date,then=10),default=F('capacity'))
```

- We check whether `modified_at` is less than `your_date`
- then the value of this condition is 10,
- else, we keep the same value of the field with `F('capacity')`

**rest of the code**

```
Room.objects.update_or_create(name='new_name',
           defaults={'name':'new_name','capacity':conditition})
```

Comment: This code is susceptible to race conditions. We can put this code in an atomic transaction block but I was just wondering whether there's a better way

Comment: I edited my answer, added another way to do it, this one is more efficient @user9724623

Comment: This is awesome @Lemayzeur, but then i'll have to add conditions for every attribute in the model, rather i want to bulk update, i.e update every attribute if condition satisfies or leave as it is. Look at my query above for better clarity as to what i mean

Comment: so you don't need to use `update_or_create`, but rather `queryset.update()`  it will do what you want

Comment: but it won't create if the row doesn't exist, and i want - if row exits then update only if the time condition satisfies other wise create a new row

Comment: exactly, the 2nd option does